# Expand parameter pack in calling the base types' methods when variadic template class is inherited from template arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

So basically I want to define a class that inherits from an arbitrary amount of classes and have a method in it that calls the overloaded method from all the base classes.

I tried writing this, but it won't compile:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::method()\n";
    }
};

class Bar
{
public:
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << "Bar::method()\n";
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
class Combined: public Ts...
{
public:
    Combined(const Ts&... ts): Ts(ts)... {}
    Combined(Ts&&... ts): Ts(std::move(ts))... {}

    template <typename U>
    void call_methods()
    {
        U::method();
    }

    template <typename U, typename... Us>
    void call_methods()
    {
        U::method();
        call_methods<Us...>();
    }

    void method()
    {
        call_methods<Ts...>();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Combined<Foo, Bar> obj({}, {});
    obj.method();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler says the following:

```
test.cpp:42:9: error: call to member function 'call_methods' is ambiguous
        call_methods<Us...>();
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:47:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'Combined<Foo, Bar>::call_methods<Foo, Bar>' requested here
        call_methods<Ts...>();
        ^
test.cpp:57:9: note: in instantiation of member function
      'Combined<Foo, Bar>::method' requested here
    obj.method();
        ^
test.cpp:33:10: note: candidate function [with U = Bar]
    void call_methods()
         ^
test.cpp:39:10: note: candidate function [with U = Bar, Us = <>]
    void call_methods()
         ^
```

Basically there is an ambiguity between `call_methods<U = Bar>` and `call_methods<U = Bar, Us = <>>`. But if I declare a `void call_methods() {}`, it won't match the `call_methods<Us...>();` for some reason.

If it's not clear yet, I want `Combined<Foo, Bar>::method()` to call `Foo::method()` and `Bar::method()`.

I know that I can probably implement this by having a `tuple` with the objects of corresponding types as a member and just iterating over them, but I really want to find a solution that's closer to what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your solution, disable the second overload when parameter pack is empty:

```
template <typename U, typename... Us>
typename std::enable_if< (sizeof...(Us) > 0) >::type
call_methods()
{
    U::method();
    call_methods<Us...>();
}
```

Gets rid of ambiguity.

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abf6bfcd23a7eb6c)

Comment: But what if I want to `call_method` to return something?

Comment: Declare it accordingly? :) `enable_if` lets you specify the `type`, if that's what you mean. Its second template parameter [defaults to `void` .](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Comment: `sizeof...(Us) > 0` will not compile, as `>` will be interpreted as a template argument list closing bracket. either remove `>0` or invert operands

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki it compiles for me when surrounded with parenthesis

Comment: @gmoshkin yes, that's the third option. the original code did not have any parenthesis

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki also removing `> 0` will result in instantiation where `sizeof...(Us)` is not 0 or 1 not compiling, due to other values not being convertible to `bool`

Comment: @gmoshkin any non-zero value is implicitly convertible to true

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to this problem. The easiest would be to expand call in place, rather than recursively. Something along following lines:

```
struct Foo
{
    void method();
};

struct Bar
{
    void method();
};

template <typename... Ts>
class Combined: public Ts...
{
public:
    Combined(const Ts&... ts);
    Combined(Ts&&... ts);

    void method()
    {

        bool z[] = { (Ts::method(), true)... };
        (void)z;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Combined<Foo, Bar> obj({}, {});
    obj.method();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `auto z = {(Ts::method(), 0) ...};` would work. I'm not sure I get the point of `call()` helper.

Answer (score 1):

Tackling the *why* of the error, this happens because overload resolution is concerned with function parameters and not function template parameters.

The instantiation `foo<Bar>()` is indistinguishable from overload resolution (*the one with one parameter or the one with an empty parameter pack?*), hence it ends up with an ambiguity in the call.

As mentioned in the [SergeyA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53961047/1316462), a way to solve this is to have just one overload and do `in-site` expansion of the call.

Comment: Ok this solves the question I asked, but as it turns out I didn't ask the question I needed answered :) I actually want the methods to return a value and I don't want to iterate over them dynamically, seeing as the amount of iterations is known statically. Any help with that?

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions:

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Combined: public Ts...
{
public:
    Combined(const Ts&... ts): Ts(ts)... {}
    Combined(Ts&&... ts): Ts(std::move(ts))... {}

    void method()
    {
        int dummy[] { (Ts::method(), 0)... };
    }
};
```

Not ideal but should be as efficient as my original idea.

Comment: Since it is effectively my answer, I am curious why you think this is *not ideal*.

Comment: @SergeyA well it looks more like a hack than other solutions and it is kinda harder to read for me at least. I guess it's just personal preference.